# Simulating time series data using arima.sim with intercept and xreg

Tags: simulation, arima

I have fitted a time series dataset with ARIMA model that includes xreg using

```
library(tseries)
library(forecast)
library(ggplot2)

model4 = auto.arima(z, xreg = lvl, stepwise = F, approximation = F, trace = T, d = 0)
```

The results of the model fitting are ARIMA(4,0,1) with xreg are

```
summary(model4)

Series: z 
Regression with ARIMA(4,0,1) errors 

Coefficients:
         ar1      ar2     ar3      ar4      ma1  intercept    xreg
      1.7979  -1.0159  0.3085  -0.0963  -0.9462    55.8895  12.709
s.e.  0.0164   0.0260  0.0244   0.0127   0.0113     1.2883   2.065

sigma^2 = 140.9:  log likelihood = -28198.32
AIC=56412.65   AICc=56412.67   BIC=56467.75

Training set error measures:
                      ME    RMSE     MAE       MPE    MAPE      MASE         ACF1
Training set 0.001213663 11.8654 7.51428 -3.137279 13.7287 0.9375283 -0.001053871
```

Here xreg is a dummy variable that indicates Yes if event happened and vice versa.
How do I simulate a dataset which includes `model4` as the base?
I tried

```
simdata = arima.sim(model = list(ar = c(1.7979,-1.0159,0.3085,-0.0963), ma = -0.9462), n = 1000)
```

But I do not know how to include the intercept and xreg information in the simulation. I am open to learning other way of simulating data other than `arima.sim`.

EDIT

I used a bootstrapping technique referring to [this link](https://otexts.com/fpp2/bootstrap.html).
My codes are

```
bootseries = bld.mbb.bootstrap(z, num = 10) %>% 
     as.data.frame() %>% 
     ts(start = 1997, frequency = 365)
```

which gives me 10 sets of bootstrapping datasets. However, these simulations are based on data and not the fitted model.